# Symfony Workflow - Is it possible to use doctrine relation as state holder?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-workflows

I am trying to adopt the Symfony workflow component to my app.

As documentation says `marking_store` points to string. I was googling for it - it can be a `string` or `json_array`-field of a Doctrine entity.

But what if I have an Entity `BlogPost` with a relation `BlogPostStatus` that have two fields: some primary `id` and `statusName`. Can I configure the workflow component to change statuses of my `BlogPost` (i.e set new `BlogPostStatus` to `BlogPost` entity) and persist it to database?

Now I have only one solution: Add to my `BlogPost` entity non-mapped field and when it's changed change status of Entity.

Do you have a better solution?

Comment: There was a recent change in Workflow allowing for custom contexts. It looks to me that this is what could solve your problem. You could pass the new `BlogPostStatus` in the context and set it. Does that solve it for you? See: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-workflow-improvements#added-a-context-to-workflow-apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all built-in marking_store implementations the following is true:

If the functions `setMarking` or `getMarking` exist on the object holding the state, they will be used to set or get the marking respectively.

There are 3 built-in marking stores, the [`SingleStateMarkingStore`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/src/Symfony/Component/Workflow/MarkingStore/SingleStateMarkingStore.php) (using the property accessor, hence setMarking/getMarking), the [`MultiStateMarkingStore`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/src/Symfony/Component/Workflow/MarkingStore/MultipleStateMarkingStore.php) (same), the [`MethodMarkingStore`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/src/Symfony/Component/Workflow/MarkingStore/MethodMarkingStore.php) (explicitly calling those functions, you can change the function via the `property` setting of your `marking_store` config).

The difference lies within the argument provided in the `setMarking` call, for single state (this is the `state_machine` type, and by default NOT the the `workflow` type), the argument is the **place** (or state) where the mark is placed. For multi state (`workflow` type by default), the argument is an **array** where the keys are places and the values are marks, usually the marks are `1`, and empty places are omitted.

So, I'll assume that your `BlogPost` (currently) only has a single state at any given time, and what you have to do now is to transform the marking given into the status entity - I will assume your workflow has type `state_machine`:

```
/** in class BlogPost */
public function setMarking(string $marking/*, array $context*/) {
    $this->status->statusName = $marking;
}

public function getMarking() {
    return $this->status->statusName;
}
```

#### special cases

If the `BlogPostStatus` should be a *different* one (for example, a constant object), then you'd have to use the [new interface that dbrumann linked](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-workflow-improvements), and hook into the event to add that to the context.

If the BlogPostStatus may not exist at the time of the setMarking/getMarking, you have to create it on the fly in the setter and check for it in the getter. But I'm sure you're capable of doing that ;o)

Also if you're not using the single state workflows but multi state instead, you have to find a way to transform the array of (places->marks) into your status object and vice versa.